Is an individual pointer within a page table indexed the same way as any other logical address?
I have found the following diagrams while researching how paging works in Linux.
+-----+
| PGD |
+-----+
   |
   |   +-----+
   +-->| P4D |
       +-----+
          |
          |   +-----+
          +-->| PUD |
              +-----+
                 |
                 |   +-----+
                 +-->| PMD |
                     +-----+
                        |
                        |   +-----+
                        +-->| PTE |


      PMD
--> +-----+           PTE
    | ptr |-------> +-----+
    | ptr |-        | ptr |-------> PAGE
    | ptr | \       | ptr |
    | ptr |  \        ...
    | ... |   \
    | ptr |    \         PTE
    +-----+     +----> +-----+
                       | ptr |-------> PAGE
                       | ptr |
                         ...

It's my understanding that each logical address is split and indexed the following ways:
For 32-bit systems: 10 + 10 + 12 = 32 bits
For 64-bit systems: 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 12 = 48 bits
So, considering this information I have the following question. Is an individual pointer (or "ptr" as in the 2nd diagram) within a page table indexed the same way as any other logical address? Meaning if it is, then a new hierarchical structure of PGD's (to P4D's, etc) is created and so on and so forth...
Or, am I missing something big here that I am not seeing and understanding?

Page directory entries and page table entries, with the “present” bit set, store (portions of) physical addresses. This means they can be walked without having to recurse. (Your question describes 64-bit x86 paging, not Linux paging.)
In 64-bit mode, each page directory stores 512 entries, which corresponds to the 9 bits decoded at each level (29 = 512).

I can see now my assumption was wrong. My real question was how each page directory table entry points to another, individual table of page directory entries when each page table can only hold a certain amount of entries? And, how large are the pointers in each page table?

Also, I must of got the wrong type of diagram when searching online that concerned Linux. My bad.
